# Rails routing: putting matches for routing in a function to reduce complexity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, routes, rails-routing

I have a rails application that does some upfront scoping to handle multiple subdomains and multiple languages but results in having two sets of inner matches that are identical. I would like to break these inner matches out to a function so that I can reduce and reuse code I cannot find any examples of someone doing this in the routes.

Code:

```
constraints lambda { |request| request.subdomains[0].include? "internal" } do
  scope ":hash" do 
    get '/', to: 'product#index'
    get '/:productID', to: 'product#show'
  end
  get "", to: 'product#no_hash'
  get "/*path", to: 'product#no_hash'
end

constraints lambda { |request| !request.subdomains[0].include? "internal" } do
  scope ":hash" do 
    get '/', to: 'product#index'
    get '/:productID', to: 'product#show'
  end
end
```

Again the goal is to get the inner matches placed into a function so that I can reduce duplication, reuse code, and save the world. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have two answers:

First one: actually your shared routes do not depend on your subdomain, so you could just write them out of your constraints, they would be directly shared.

---

Another one, with a function

```
def shared_routes
  scope ":hash" do 
    get '/', to: 'product#index'
    get '/:productID', to: 'product#show'
  end
end

constraints lambda { |request| request.subdomains[0].include? "internal" } do
  shared_routes
  get "", to: 'product#no_hash'
  get "/*path", to: 'product#no_hash'
 end

constraints lambda { |request| !request.subdomains[0].include? "internal" } do
  shared_routes
end
```

---

Not sure I can help you save the world though :)

Comment: Interesting I tried that but put () after it and it failed but straight calling it worked. I changed it back to include the () and it works.... freekin ruby.